# Regexp not matching when the string contains a space

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following rule to match the pattern in a string.

> 2 alphanumeric characters, followed by 0 or 1 alphabets, followed by 0
>   or more spaces, followed by 1 to 4 digits

I tried a regexp, but I am still missing out few cases.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @quer = ('a1q 1234', '11 asdd', 'as 11aa', 'asdasdasd', 'asdd as', 'asdasd asdassdasd', '11 1231', '11 a 12345', '345 1 1231', '12a 123', 'ab 12', 'ab12');
foreach my $query (@quer) {
    if ($query =~ m/\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{0,1}\s*\b[0-9]{1,4}\b/) {
        print "Matched : $query\n";
    } else {
        print "Doesn't match : $query\n";
    }
}
```

My code is matching `ab 12` but not `ab12`, but according to the rule, it should match both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having a word boundary in the middle, which is screwing your regex. Remove it:

```
if ($query =~ m/\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{0,1}\s*\b[0-9]{1,4}\b/)
                                                 ^
                                             remove this
```

should be:

```
if ($query =~ m/\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]?\s*[0-9]{1,4}\b/)
```

Note, `[a-zA-Z]{0,1}` is same as `[a-zA-Z]?`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if ($query =~ m/\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{0,1}\s*[0-9]{1,4}\b/) {
```

It is doing exactly what u asked for!!!

Answer (score 1):

In perl (and some other languages) you have some nice shortcuts for alphanumeric, numbers and stuff like that.

e.g:

```
\w  Match "word" character (alphanumeric plus "_")
\W  Match non-word character
\s  Match whitespace character
\S  Match non-whitespace character
\d  Match digit character
\D  Match non-digit character
```

But your problem is the word boundary at the middle (`\b`)

try this:

```
if ($query =~ m/\b\w{2}\w?\s*\d{1,4}\b/)
```

Comment: For those shortcuts to be equivalent, you need to use the `/a` flag, otherwise they match Unicode characters too. Reference: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Backslash-sequences

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($query =~ m/[0-9A-z]{2}[A-z]?\s*[0-9]{1,4}$/)
```

This above code also will work.